# How to really keep together fo:inline objects in Apache FOP 1.1

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a list of authors:

```
<titleStmt>
    <author>GivenName1 Surname1</author>
    <author>GivenName2 Surname2</author>
    <author>GivenName3 Surname3</author>
    <author>GivenName4 Surname4</author>
    <author>GivenName5 Surname5</author>
    <author>GivenName6 Surname6</author>
</titleStmt>
```

After the initial transformation into XSL-FO I have:

```
<fo:block font-family="Times New Roman" text-transform="uppercase" text-align="left" font-size="8pt" line-height="11pt" margin-right="5cm">
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName1 Surname1</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName2 Surname2</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName3 Surname3</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName4 Surname4</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName5 Surname5</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName6 Surname6</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

I need to wrap lines only between every record, not inside it (don’t want to split GivenName and Surname). With `keep-together.within-line`, I would expect it should work but it doesn’t. The only one result I have is line overflowing the page border, like I applied the rule to the whole block container. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit nasty to me but adding of non-breaking spaces works as expected:

```
<fo:block font-family="Times New Roman" text-transform="uppercase" text-align="left" font-size="8pt" line-height="11pt" margin-right="5cm">
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName1&#160;Surname1</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName2&#160;Surname2</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName3&#160;Surname3</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName4&#160;Surname4</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName5&#160;Surname5</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">GivenName6&#160;Surname6</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

I am generating this with an XSL stylesheet, so:

```
<fo:inline>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s', '&#160;')"/>
</fo:inline>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your block with FOP 1.1 and the output is as expected (several lines, breaking only after the surnames).

I think you probably have a `keep-together.within-line="always"` or `keep-together="always"` (*) in an ancestor of the `fo:block`, thus forcing the whole block to produce a single line.

(*) The XSL 1.1 Recommendation, section [5.11 Property Datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#datatype), explains that:

> `keep-together="always"`
>   is equivalent to a specification of `keep-together.within-line="always"` `keep-together.within-column="always"` `keep-together.within-page="always"`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have checked all attributes and unfortunately no, there is no other `keep-together` parameter above these. I will test more.

Comment: It behaves like I put there `keep-with-next.within-line`.